# Option for RShiny on Windows server

Tags: python, r, shiny, analytics, shiny-server

Our analysis tool uses R and Shiny server for visualization, Want it to host on Windows server Ready to move to Python if it can be hosted on Windows? (Please Don't recommend for VM)

Comment: Have you looked at the ["install from source"](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source) guide? It does specify "For other Linux distributions", so I'd say you're out of luck.

Comment: [Not on Windows](https://www.rstudio.com/faq-items/shiny-server-pro-run-windows/). Technically not a VM, have you considered a docker image? The newest [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) runs on Hyper-V (instead of virtualbox).

Comment: @r2evans Windows Server belongs to one of my client so they are allowing to make any changes on system itself. I was looking at Python's Packages plotly and Spyre. Can we host Apps Developed using these tools implemented on Windows Server.

Comment: What did you find out when you looked at plotly's website? (I found a page there that said they required ["a linux OS"](https://plot.ly/products/on-premise/).) I recommend if there is any ambiguity that you just go directly to the Sales department of each company.

Comment: @r2evans  Thank you for your help...Can we just say that there is no way out?

Comment: That's completely on you, I don't know anything about your client or your contract situation (and this is definitely not the venue for discussing it).