# Plotly hosting on Windows Server

Tags: python, r, server, shiny, plotly

Our analysis tool uses R and Shiny server for visualization, Want it to host on Windows server Ready to move to Python if it can be hosted on Windows? Plotly of Python is a Shiny alternative but Can we Host it on Windows Server? (Without VM or Docker Image)

Comment: I think my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217942/option-for-rshiny-on-windows-server?noredirect=1#comment63897831_38217942) to your nearly-identical question applies here as well: plotly [requires "a linux os"](https://plot.ly/products/on-premise/).

Comment: Can we develop in algorithm in Python using Django framework and for UI part we'll use HTML or similiar and then host it on Windows Server?

Comment: If you are asking how to set up a server using different components, more appropriate SE sites could be either [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). SO is a site about programming and its issues. I don't know Django so I will not speculate.